# How can I check existence of object by Ebean?

Tags: java, ebean

I have to transfer data from one database to another and I using Ebean to store objects. How can I check out if object already was written or not? I don't know `ID`, but I know all values for all fields of object.

Comment: Note, if you know values you can query database exactly the same as in other question: possible duplicate of [How to query (EBean & Play Framework) to see if a certain value is in a certain column in a certain table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774217/how-to-query-ebean-play-framework-to-see-if-a-certain-value-is-in-a-certain)

Comment: In that post (and other examples I can find) only one field is checked. But if record contains 10 fields? How can I query database in souch case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally if you want to do it using a populated bean you could also use the 'exampleLike' expression.

```
ExampleExpression byExample = Expr.exampleLike(Object exampleBean, boolean caseInsensitive, LikeType likeType);

query.where().add(byExample)
```

That should create the expressions for you for each property.

Comment: And what about `id` I am creating new object and trying to fing existing one with all fields except `id` the same. Id my new object is always 0, cause it's just created and not persist yet. Id existing in database object is always not 0. In the theory `id` field is annotated by `@Id` and maybe I can get expected behavior. I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: It's working with no additional instructions about `id` Just like `School existing = School.find.where().exampleLike(new).findUnique();`! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Ebean API uses `AND` operator for unlimited number of params by default (sample):

```
MyModel.find.where()
  .like("email", "john@doe.com")
  .like("firstName", "John")
  .like("lastName", "Doe")
  .eq("age", 123)
  .eq("isMaried", true)
  .findRowCount();
```

Comment: With this example, it should be noted that using `ieq()` for case-insensitive comparison is probably the better approach than `like()` when comparing values like email or (user) names.